# Check all CheckBoxes in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, checkbox

I have a GridView in ASP.NET/C# with a CheckBoxField, a BoundField and 2 ButtonFields. All 4 of them has a header to make clear where the column stands for. At the Page_Load event I set the ВataЫource of the GridView to my filled DataTable.

I want to make it easier to use for the user, and want to make a checkbox in the header. When that checkbox is checked by the user, all CheckBoxes should be checked in the GridView. I have set the HeaderText of the CheckBoxField to `<input type='checkbox' />`, and it shows a checkbox in the header now.

Now I want to add a function to that checkbox, that when it's checked, all CheckBoxes will be checked en vice versa. I tried to do it with jQuery, but it didn't work because I can't find a way to give all the CheckBoxes in the GridView the same ID or NAME.

Is there a event that occurs when I check the HTML based checkbox within the header? If yes, which event?
If no, how can i trigger a event when I check that checkbox, and change the GridView from my code-behind.

And if none of that is possible, how can i do it on another way, with javascript, jQuery or maybe with a ASP.net control.

I hope you can help me with this, but please don't expect i'm a code guru. I'm a intern at a company where the need a system, with this functionality.

**Update:**

Thank you everyone for helping me out. What is the easiest way to get the DataSource back into the DataTable, because i need to know which rows were selected and which were not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, you get all the check boxes inside the GridView, and then for each one you change the status as you like. You call this javascript function from onclick of a link or a button, or what ever you like.

```
function CheckAll()
{   
    var updateButtons = jQuery('#<%=gvGridViewId.ClientID%> input[type=checkbox]');

    updateButtons.each( function() {
            // use this line to change the status if check to uncheck and vice versa
            //  or make it as you like with similar function
        jQuery(this).attr("checked", !this.checked);
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code according to you

in grid view

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>                                
            <asp:CheckBox ID="headerchkbox" runat="server"  CssClass="chkheader" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxAssign" runat="server" CssClass="chkitems" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).bind('load', function () {
            var headerChk = $(".chkheader input");
            var itemChk = $(".chkitems input");
            headerChk.bind("click", function () { itemChk.each(function () { this.checked = headerChk[0].checked; })
            });
            itemChk.bind("click", function () { if ($(this).checked == false) headerChk[0].checked = false; });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample I have put together for you.

**ASPX**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var allCheckBoxSelector = '#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> input[id*="chkAll"]:checkbox';
        var checkBoxSelector = '#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> input[id*="chkSelected"]:checkbox';

        function ToggleCheckUncheckAllOptionAsNeeded() {
            var totalCheckboxes = $(checkBoxSelector),
         checkedCheckboxes = totalCheckboxes.filter(":checked"),
         noCheckboxesAreChecked = (checkedCheckboxes.length === 0),
         allCheckboxesAreChecked = (totalCheckboxes.length === checkedCheckboxes.length);

            $(allCheckBoxSelector).attr('checked', allCheckboxesAreChecked);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(allCheckBoxSelector).live('click', function () {
                $(checkBoxSelector).attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

                ToggleCheckUncheckAllOptionAsNeeded();
            });

            $(checkBoxSelector).live('click', ToggleCheckUncheckAllOptionAsNeeded);

            ToggleCheckUncheckAllOptionAsNeeded();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**C#**

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<string> lstObjects = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb" };
                GridView1.DataSource = lstObjects;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

### If you are using the latest version of jQuery (1.7)

Use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var allCheckBoxSelector = '#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> input[id*="chkAll"]:checkbox';
        var checkBoxSelector = '#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> input[id*="chkSelected"]:checkbox';

        function ToggleCheckUncheckAllOptionAsNeeded() {
            var totalCheckboxes = $(checkBoxSelector),
         checkedCheckboxes = totalCheckboxes.filter(":checked"),
         noCheckboxesAreChecked = (checkedCheckboxes.length === 0),
         allCheckboxesAreChecked = (totalCheckboxes.length === checkedCheckboxes.length);

            $(allCheckBoxSelector).attr('checked', allCheckboxesAreChecked);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(allCheckBoxSelector).click(function () {
                $(checkBoxSelector).attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

                ToggleCheckUncheckAllOptionAsNeeded();
            });

            $(checkBoxSelector).click(ToggleCheckUncheckAllOptionAsNeeded);

            ToggleCheckUncheckAllOptionAsNeeded();
        });
    </script>
```