# asp.net select all/none checkboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript or Jquery to check and uncheck all checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730471/javascript-or-jquery-to-check-and-uncheck-all-checkbox)

I have 12 asp:checkboxes on a page and I would like to add one which selects/deselects all of them.
What's the best way to do that?

I've seen people use jquery but I'm not very familiar with JS.
IS there a generic jquery finction to use?

```
<head>...
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...</head>

<body>...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Selectall() {
            if ($('.JchkAll').is(':checked')) {
                // .JchkGrid cssClass will be assigned to all other checkboxes in your control 
                $('.JchkGrid').attr('checked', 'true');
            }
            else {
                $('.JchkGrid').removeAttr('checked', 'false');
            }
        } 
    </script>
<form>...
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbSelectAll" Text="Select/Deselect All" CssClass="JchkAll" onchange="Selectall();"/>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbName" Text="Name" class="JchkGrid"/>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbModel" Text="Model" CssClass="JchkGrid"/>
...</form>
...</body>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177159/jquery-toggle-checkboxes-on-off

Comment: Not quite, I need a way to do it for asp:checkbox type, not input type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your chckbox a css class and try this way

`// .JchkAll is cssclass of your checkbox on which's click you need to check all Checkboxes`

```
function Selectall() {
  if ($('.JchkAll').is(':checked')) {
   // .JchkGrid cssClass will be assigned to all other checkboxes in your control
    $('.JchkGrid').attr('checked', 'true');
  }
  else {
    $('.JchkGrid').removeAttr('checked', 'false');
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Also Don't forget to add this on checkbox's onchange attribute..

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" onchange="Selectall();" ID="cbSelectAll" 
     Text="Select/Deselect All" CssClass="JchkAll"/>
```

But this will give you a compiler warning...it would be better if you add it from code behind on Page_Load event like

```
    cbSelectAll.Attributes.Add("onchange","Selectall");
```

Comment: JchkGrid would be the CSS class for each checkbox, and JchkAll the CSS class for the checkbox which selects/deselects all?

Comment: I'm not getting any joy. Here is how the checkboxes are done: `<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbSelectAll" Text="Select/Deselect All" CssClass="JchkAll"/>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbName" Text="Name" Checked="true" CssClass="JchkGrid"/>`

Comment: you forgot to add <asp:CheckBox runat="server"onchange="Selectall();" ID="cbSelectAll" Text="Select/Deselect All" CssClass="JchkAll"/>

Comment: oh yes. I have just added that but still no go. I have `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the head, and the jquery in a `<script>` in body. Does that sound good?

Comment: Yes, btw it should work...try check your css class and that must be case insensitive...

Comment: I have it exactly as above, I get no warnings/errors at compile time, it just never ticks/unticks anything.

Comment: can you please post your code..by editing your first post..

Comment: you should keep your all the <script> in your <head> tag...

Comment: have tried it just now. still nothing. can't believe how something so simple be so annoying.

Comment: Well, Seems some problem from your end..I would recommend you to check all the things with cool mind okay...take it easy..if it doesn't gets fixed then no need to get annoyed Everyone is here to help you...

Comment: Ok I have tried one of the other samples below http://jsfiddle.net/a2XeK/ which does work. Now how to get that work with the asp:checkbox type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543017/javascript-check-all-checkboxes-in-a-table-asp-net this seems to do the trick. thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

First you find all the checkboxes, and then you change them. This you done on client via javascript. For example this is a function that if you call it is check all the chekboxes on a page.

```
function SwapCheck()
{   
    // find them
    var allChecks = jQuery('input[type=checkbox]');

    allChecks.each( function() {
        jQuery(this).prop("checked", !this.checked);
        // use this for jQuery ver 1.6 and before
        // jQuery(this).attr("checked", !this.checked);
    });     
}
```

If you like to eliminate some checkboxs then warp them with a span, or div and use the

```
jQuery('#DivIDWithChecksToSelect input[type=checkbox]');
```

If you like to check them all you can use this code

```
jQuery(this).attr("checked", "checked");
```

Also you can use the `jQuery(this).prop("checked", false);` to uncheck them.

relative:
[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)
[Check all CheckBoxes in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886056/check-all-checkboxes-in-gridview)

About the `.attr()` and the `.prop()` read here : http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I did jQuery(this).prop("checked", !this.checked);

Comment: @HughSeagraves thank you for the note, this is very old answer 4 years ago, after ver 1.6 the prop() method is better

Answer (score 1):

Give your checkboxes one CssClass name (chk_group in my example), and the give your check box that will change all of them another CssClass name (chk_select_all in my example)

then you can try this jQuery code

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chk_select_all input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
       $(".chk_group input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', this.checked); 
    });
 });​
```

Check here a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/a2XeK/

In ASP.NET WebForms, you'll have to use the selector .chk_select_all input[type=checkbox] because the rendering engine will create a  with css style, and inside the span there will be the actual checkbox.

Comment: Can't get it to work for asp:checkboxes

Comment: but it works fine for input type=checkbox, how to make the asp:checkbox to work too?

Comment: I see that asp.net renders the checkbox into a span tag, and assigns the style class to the span. I'm updating my solution with a note.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do it. See which is best for you. Using JavaScript

```
function toggleCheckboxes(flag) {    
    var form = document.getElementById('groupImportForm');
    var inputs = form.elements;
    if(!inputs){
        //console.log("no inputs found");
        return;
    }
    if(!inputs.length){
        //console.log("only one elements, forcing into an array");
        inputs = new Array(inputs);        
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
      //console.log("checking input");
      if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {  
        inputs[i].checked = flag;
      }  
    }  
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in the codebehind if you want. In the OnCheckedChanged event of the main checkbox, set all of the Checked variables of the checkboxes to true.

Comment: it can be done at client side easily...there is no need of iterating Control on client side...

Comment: Have tried that but need a way to do it witohut postback.